# Iterative method for fixed point of a mapping with domain and range contained in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, numerical-integration, algorithm, iteration

Let $X$ be a metric space and $T:X\rightarrow X$ be a function. A point $x\in X$ is called a fixed point of $T$ if $x=Tx$. For example, if $X=[0,1]$ and $Tx=\frac{x}{2}$ then $T$ has a unique fixed point $x=0$. Now I can compute this fixed by the iterative method $x_{n}=Tx_{n-1}$ where $n=1,2,3,...$ and $x_{0}\in X$ is any initial guess. My code is the following

```
T[x_] := T[x] = (x/2)
x[0] = 0.1;
x[n_] := x[n] = T[x[n - 1]]
NumberForm[a1 = Table[x[i], {i, 0, 20}], 4]
```

After run this, I get the values as

```
0.1, 0.05, 0.025, 0.0125, 0.00625, 0.003125, 0.0015625
```

Now I have a problem in coding and no idea how I set the code similar to my above code when the domain and range are in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. For example if $X=[0,1]\times [0,1]$ and set $T:X\rightarrow X$ by $T(x,y)=(\frac{x}{2},\frac{y}{3})$ then $(0,0)$ is the unique fixed point of $T$. Now how is compute this fixed point by the iterative method above in this case in mathematica?

Comment: You can represent points as lists with 2 elements, e.g. `T[{x_,y_}] := {x/2,y/3}`.

Answer (score 3):

- Iterative the mapping `Apply[{x, y} |-> {x/2, y/3}]`.

```
pts = NestList[Apply[{x, y} |-> {x/2, y/3}], {20., 10.}, 10]
Graphics[{{Red, Point[pts]}, Blue, Arrowheads[.025], 
  Arrow /@ Partition[pts, 2, 1]}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

- Calculate the fixed point by `DiscrteLimit`.

```
DiscreteLimit[
 RSolveValue[{x[n + 1] == x[n]/2, y[n + 1] == y[n]/3, x[0] == x0, 
   y[0] == y0}, {x[n], y[n]}, n], n -> ∞]
```

> {0,0}

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
FixedPoint[(#/2) &, x, 10]
(* x/1024 *)
```

and play with its last argument 10, 15, 100...

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

**2-D Fixed-point iteration to solve Lame-Embden integral equation with matrix multiplication**

*You can modify the attached code for your or another problem. The code shows how to deal with finding a root via the fixed-point iteration in 2D.*

For example, you have a Lame-Emden equation in the integral form
$$h(x)=1+\int _0^R\frac{y^2}{\max (x,y)}\,\,h(y)\,y\,\text{dy}$$
where $R$ is a positive constant, e.g. star radius. Namely, the smallest real root of $h(R)=0$.
The problem can be discretized using the grid
$$x_i= \left(i-\frac{1}{2}\right)\text{$\Delta $x},\,\,\,i=1,\text{...},n$$

where $\Delta x=\frac{R}{n}$ is the grid spacing. Using the mid-point rule, integration amounts to matrix multiplication, i.e. our integral equation can be written as
$$h_i=1+\sum _{j=1}^n M_{\text{ij}} h_j$$
where $h_i=h (x_i)$ and
$$M_{\text{ij}}=\text{$\Delta $x}\text{ }\left(\frac{x_j^2}{\max \left(x_i,x_j\right)}-x_j\right)$$
Therefore, we can solve our equation by iterating the matrix as follows
$$h_{\text{new}}=1+M\cdot h_{\text{old}}$$
As an initial guess, use $h_i=h (x_i)=1$

```
n=32; R=Pi; step=R/n; (*inputs*)
(* equidistant x-grid; mid-point rule allows to avoid origin, i.e. division by 0*)
x=Table[(i-0.5)*step, {i,1,n}]; 
(*We conversed the integral eq. into discrete summation. The scheme relies on matrix multiplication.*)
M=step*Table[(x[[j]])^2/Max[x[[i]],x[[j]]]-x[[j]], {i,1,n}, {j,1,n}];(*matrix updated at each step*)
(*we start from vector of 1's; next the vector of solutions at each grid is updated*)
h=Table[1., {i,1,n}]; 
err = ConstantArray[1, {100}]; (*for pre-allocation*)
count = ConstantArray[1, {100}];

eps = 10^(-14);
MaxIter = 100;
k=2;

While[k<= MaxIter && err[[k-1]] > eps, (*impose conditions*)
   hold=h; (*start*)
   hnext = 1+M . hold; (*dot vector onto matrix to update*)
   err[[k]] = Norm[hnext-hold]; (*errors*)
   h=hnext;
   count[[k]]=k;
   k++];
(*To display results*)
errors=Transpose[{count=DeleteCases[count,1]-1,DeleteCases[err, 1]}];
head = {"Iterations", "Error"};
Prepend[errors,head]//MatrixForm
Print["The solution vector at each point of grid is: ", h]
```

We can plot obtained numerical estimation of the root whose value approximates to the $\pi$ value, as it is demonstrated in the image below.
Let's plot the solution

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{x,h}],
         PlotStyle->Magenta, AxesLabel->{"x","h(x)"}, PlotLabel->"Numerical solution" ,
         ImageSize->Scaled[0.6]]
```

[image]